# jquery mega menu mouse hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a MEGA MENU using jquery and css using the following code:

```
$(".sub-menu").find('a.amenu').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu-panel").show();
    }
    ,function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu-panel").hide();
    }
);
```

where the menu links has a class called "sub-menu" and the panel related to it  has a class called "sub-menu-panel".

How to keep the related panel of a menu link visible if the mouse hover it ?
my problem is when i move the mouse over a panel to click any sub-link on it the panel it self disapeared because the mouse out event fired when i leave the main link.

Comment: I think the problem is in your HTML markup, maybe there is a way to make it better, even in pure css. However, with details you attach here, this should be closed. You need to provide a working example.

Comment: Can you post your code? Any html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - providing an example of what you're trying to explain would be advantageous to getting a working response.

Secondly - you shouldn't need any javascript/jQuery to show a submenu on hover - a simple `:hover` mechanic in CSS should give you the effect you want.